# how to reorder columns in a google spreadsheet

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I would like to programmatically reorder the columns in a Google spreadsheet, preferably with the python client library. Any ideas on how to do this using the API itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

download it as a xls file. use xlrd to read the content and xlwt to write back. See [python-excel](http://www.python-excel.org/)

for example:

```
import xlrd
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('myworkbook.xls')
b.sheet_names()
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
col = sh.col_values(0)
.....
```

just refer to the documents of the package

===========================

**EDIT**: if you want a more "elegant" way, that is google' own api, you can check this [link](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/). But it seems google only provides java API.

Comment: Thanks! - pretty nasty, but should get the trick done for my current purposes. Does this mean there's no way to do so from within gdata?